# My switch structure dosent seem to work(JavaScript control structure)

Tags: javascript

Nothing shows up in browser and since JavaScript doesn't have a compiler to run it though I am not sure how to check for errors in this language.

my HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Where am I?></title>
    <script src="script4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

My script4.js

```javascript
var number = 20;
switch(number) {
  case number > 0:
    alert(number + " is Positive");
    break;
  case number ===  0:
    alert(number + " is zero");
    break;
  case number < 0;
    alert(number + " is negative");
  default:
    alert(number + " is not a number");
}
```

Comment: Each of recent browsers have "developer tools" (normally F12), please check out if you have errors in the console view of the tools (i.e. for IE F12, click on "script" tab). Post error in your question.

Comment: side note - you're missing a `break;` in the `number < 0` case.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript will compare each case expression with the switch value, so you can just use a switch value of `true` to enable you to write boolean case expressions, e.g.:

```
switch(true) 
{
    case number > 0:
        alert(number + " is Positive");
        break;
    case number ===  0:
        alert(number + " is zero");
        break;
    case number < 0:
        alert(number + " is negative");
        break;
    default:
        alert(number + " is not a number");
}
```

[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/N7cjz/)

Note that while this is a common pattern to me (and a feature I wish existed in other languages like C#), some developers may find it unconventional.

Comment: +1 Interesting use of `switch` in javascript that I've never seen before.

Comment: +1, i prefer this approach instead of nested if-else-if regardless of what JSLint says.

Comment: While this works, I don't think this is a better approach than an if-else. An `if-else` explicitly demonstrates to anyone reading the code that you are working through specific cases. Using `switch` in this manner is clever, but not obvious.

Comment: @Vivin How is a switch not about working through specific cases? I don't follow your reasoning. `if/else` statements require the developer to mentally parse the control flow, whereas with switch, it is clearly just a list of comparisons. My answer is not particularly clever, rather just an idom with which you are not familiar.

Comment: `if-else` is normally used to work through specific boolean cases. The argument to `switch` is normally a specific variable. Using `switch` in this manner seems to me more of an abuse of `switch`. Just because it works, isn't a reason to use it. `if-else` exists for this specific case, whereas a `switch` is syntactic sugar for matching the value of a variable to something specific instead of doing `if-else-if` where you're comparing values with `===`. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: @Vivin, given your argument, is it safe to say that you think *all* uses of `switch` statements where the `case` labels are (complex) expressions is invalid?  i.e.  Do you think that's a broken part of Javasript?

Comment: Great question. Generally when I see expressions in labels, it just tells me that there's something funny happening and that it could possibly be done better. I mean, I guess you could use a function that returns a value as a case label, but then it's not immediately obvious what the `switch` is looking for. IMHO it makes the code a little harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how a `switch` statement is usually used. The argument to `case` must be a number, string or a boolean (in this case you could use an expression that resolves to a boolean, but I don't see why you would have to do that instead of using an `if`; I find the latter easier to read and understand):

```
switch(number) {
   case 1: 
      alert("number is 1");
      break;
   ...
   ...

   default:
      alert("Unknown number");
}
```

What you should be using here is `if/else`:

```
if(number > 0) {
   alert("number is positive");

} else if(number === 0) {
   alert("number is zero");

} else if(number < 0) {
   alert("number is negative");

} else {
   alert("not a number");
}
```

What happens when you use a boolean expression is that the argument to `switch` is compared against the boolean values of `true` or `false`. So you're basically comparing the numerical value of `number` against `true` or `false`, and that's never going to match.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least have the courtesy to explain why.

Comment: There is no reason not to use a switch for a bunch of boolean expression comparisons. This is a fairly common pattern for JavaScript in my experience. I am not convinced there is any inherent improvement by using `if/else if` statements.

Comment: How does that warrant a downvote? Downvotes are for *wrong* answers. Nothing I've written is inherently wrong; my approach is just different. I find `if-else` to be more readable IMHO.

Comment: I am not sure you believe your definition of a downvote, because it looks like you gave me a retaliatory one. But I am also not convinced your answer warrants one, and have removed mine :)

Comment: I did downvote initially because I though the argument to your `switch` used `number` instead of `true` (I was wrong - I read it too fast). I tried to undo it after posting my comments, but I need you to edit your answer so that I can :).

Answer (score 1):

I had no idea that RedFilter's solution would work.  (Good to know!)  In most C-based languages, you can only mach against specific values.  So generally, an `if/else` chain is used:

```
if (number > 0) 
    alert(number + " is Positive");
else if (number === 0)
    alert(number + " is zero");
else if (number < 0)
    alert(number + " is negative");
else 
    alert(number + " is not a number");
```